# Unable to send JSON data to server from javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I need to send JSON data to a server method.

This method works when I pass a simple 'test' string, but not the one that follows:

```
function SendToServer() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/SaveClientGrid",
        data: "{ gridData: 'test' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
function SendToServer() {
    var data = JSON.stringify(datasource);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/SaveClientGrid",
        data: "{ gridData: " + data + " }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Does the data not reach the server? Is it faulty? Error messages?

Comment: try : `data: { gridData: data }`. And please post your error messages from either your backend or your console

Comment: did you tried var data = JSON.stringify({gridData:datasource}); and data:data in ajax object ?

Comment: var data = JSON.stringify(datasource); console.log(data); will help you

Comment: The data doesn't reach the server. I have a break point in my server method, which hits when I send 'test' string, but not when I send JSON data.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `data` variable contains what it should? In any case it's usually better to do `data: { gridData: datasource }` and let jQuery handle the conversion to JSON.

Comment: try : data: "{ gridData: '" + data + "' }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it, this one works:

```
function SendToServer() {
    var data = JSON.stringify(datasource);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/SaveClientGrid",
        data: "{ gridData: '" + data + "' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

I just had to add single quotes around the data -

```
 data: "{ gridData: '" + data + "' }"
```

Comment: Try and see if this works also: `data: JSON.stringify({'gridData': data})`

Comment: Your answer won't work properly if your server is configured properly

Comment: data: JSON.stringify({'gridData': data}) didn't work

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried changing

```
data: "{ gridData: " + data + " }",
```

to

```
data: "{ gridData: ' + data + ' }",
```

or even without the quotes? Maybe a stupid guess, but stuff like this happens all the time :)

Comment: I tried all these: data: "{ gridData: " + data + " }";  data:data; data: "{ gridData: ' + data + ' }"; the last one hits the server but the value turns to be the string ' + data + ' instead of the content of data variable

Comment: What does 
data: "{ gridData: 'JSON.stringify(datasource)' }"; 
return?

Comment: it sends the string 'JSON.stringify(datasource)' instead of it's value

Comment: So my idea to play around with the quotes got -2 points as the only other answer even if it was very close to the answer. What kind of people give this negative ratings ffs?!